# Shell script to sort & mv file based on date

Tags: unix, scripting, programming-languages

Im new to unix,I have search a lot of info but still don not how to make it in a bash

What i know is used this command `ls -tr|xargs -i ksh -c "mv {} ../tmp/"` to move file by file.

Now I need to make a script that sorts all of these files by system date and moves them into a directory, The first 1000 oldest files being to be moved.

Example files r like these

`KPK.AWQ07102011.66.6708.01`
`KPK.AWQ07102011.68.6708.01`
`KPK.EER07102011.561.8312.13`
`KPK.WWS07102011.806.3287.13`

-----------This is the script tat i hv been created-------

```
if [ ! -d /app/RAID/Source_Files/test/testfolder ] then    
                echo "test directory does not exist!"    
                mkdir /app/RAID/Source_Files/calvin/testfolder    
                echo "unused_file directory created!"    
fi

echo "Moving xx oldest files to test directory"

ls -tr  /app/RAID/Source_Files/test/*.Z|head -1000|xargs -i ksh -c "mv {} /app/RAID/Source_Files/test/testfolder/"
```

---

the problem of this script is
1) unix prompt a syntax erro 'if'
2) The move command is working but it create a new filename testfolder instead move to  directory testfolder (testfolder alredy been created in this path)

anyone can gv me a hand ? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "sort them by date"? Sort them into different directories based on the date?

Answer (score 1):

Could this help?

```
mv `ls -tr|head -1000` ../tmp/
```

`head -n` takes the n first lines of the previous command (here the 1000 oldest files). The backticks allow for the result of `ls` and `head` commands to be used as arguments to `mv`.

Comment: thanks for u reply..i need to mk it in a .sh file..can you help me find out wht is the error on my script ..thanks

Comment: aren't you missing a ; in the first line?
`if [ ! -d /app/RAID/Source_Files/test/testfolder ]; then`
and i would try my suggestion above, i don't know why you need xargs.